# Unable to scroll more horizontally to the right(only in iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

On my page there is a form that I have placed on the right side.

It fits the page in all browsers perfectly in PC. In Android browsers, even if it doesn't fit, the page can be scrollable to the right to view it fully. But in iOS devices, the page can only be scrolled only slightly to the right, not revealing the rest of the form.

**iOS look:**
[image]

**Android look:** 
[image]

I don't mind that the form doesnt fit properly in phone devices, I just want it to be able to be scrollable horizontally to view the form fully.
But since it already can be scrolled to view fully in Androids, how do I do that for iOS devices?

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>

<table id="form1:loginPanel" class= "panelContain">
<tr>
<td>User ID</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
    <input id = "form1:userID"  name : "form1:userID" type="text" value class = "loginInput">
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>Password</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="password" id = "form1:userID"  name : "form1:userPwd" type="text" value class = "loginInput2">
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
/*the body*/
body.main {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

/*the whole input form panel*/
.panelContain {
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top : 10%;
}

.loginInput {
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Calibri ;
    color: black;
}

.loginInput2 {
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Calibri ;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
```

Comment: Have you got the markup as well? In my mind the panel should be on the left based on that css.

Comment: There you go, together with the relevant HTML

Comment: Have you tried putting just that html and css into an editor? It doesn't produce your screenshot at all. This is what confused me. That css has no alignment for the panel. In fact, margin-left:0% should align left, not right.  Also, your markup contains nothing with a class of main so it's redundant. There must be some underlying css causing the alignment?

Comment: I managed to rescale the page to how I want it already, thus not needing the horizontal scrolling at all, but still I have no idea why in iOS it doesnt scroll all the way but in Android it does

Comment: My guess is that your panel is fixed with an overflow-x of hidden somewhere. You could try adding in -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: Instead of overflow-x : hidden, I put overflow-x : scroll and auto as well, and it still stayed the same. Thanks for the suggestion though @RogerWalsh, but for now I prefer to just make it not scrollable at all =)